# Hibernate Named Query Error IllegalArgumentException and QueryParameterException

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-mapping

While I try to hit the table `Data`, I always get error. Here is my POJO:

```
public class Data extends BaseObject {
    private String numb;
    private String nip;
    private String name;
    private Timestamp startDate;
    private Timestamp endDate;
    private String status;
    
    public String getNumb() {
        return numb;
    }
    public void setNumb(String numb) {
        this.numb = numb;
    }
    public String getNip() {
        return nip;
    }
    public void setNip(String nip) {
        this.nip = nip;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public Timestamp getStartDate() {
        return startDate;
    }
    public void setStartDate(Timestamp startDate) {
        this.startDate = startDate;
    }
    public Timestamp getEndDate() {
        return endDate;
    }
    public void setEndDate(Timestamp endDate) {
        this.endDate = endDate;
    }
    public String getStatus() {
        return status;
    }
    public void setStatus(String status) {
        this.status = status;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Data [numb=" + numb + ", nip=" + nip + ", name=" + name
                + ", startDate=" + startDate + ", endDate=" + endDate + ", status=" + status + "]";
    }
    
}
```

Here are the errors I got:

1. By this, I get `IllegalArgumentException: Parameter NIP does not exist as a named parameter`:

This is in the Java file

```
Query query = getCurrentSession().createQuery("select dc.nip, dc.name, dc.startDate, dc.endDate, dc.status from com.model.Data dc where dc.nip = :NIP");
q.setString("NIP", NIP);
```

2. When I use the `query.setParameter`, I got the error `org.hibernate.QueryParameterException: could not locate named parameter [NIP]`:

```
Query query = getCurrentSession().createQuery("select dc.nip, dc.name, dc.startDate, dc.endDate, dc.status from com.model.Data dc where dc.nip = :NIP");
query.setParameter("NIP", NIP);
```

So I am currently lost and not knowing what should I fix and what's wrong with those. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your parameter NIP or nip?

Comment: @UDS My parameter on the query is ":NIP"

Comment: Try by changing it to `nip`.

Comment: It was still error for me